# how to remove pages loading with the archive templates

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, archives

I have custom post type "project", and it is loading with the template "archive-project".

I already have a page "applications" to load "archive-project"

So the same page is accessible via both URL's

```
www.example.com/project  
www.example.com/applications
```

I tried a plugin "smart Archive Page Remove", which doesn't work for me.

How to remove the `www.example.com/project`

Please help.

Comment: It's loading with the template archive-project (i.e. archive-project.php)? Why can't you just delete that file?

Comment: @tmdesigned When i delete archice-project, design breaks

Comment: Do you use a custom query in `archive-project.php` and given it  a `Template Name` that you assigned to `applications` page?

Comment: @QaisarFeroz both are loading same  archive-project.php

Comment: @Vivek, that is clear from your question that both urls load same template file. I wanted to know how `archive-project.php` is codded. Please reply to my previous comment clearly so I may be able to resolve the issue or at least guide you in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `archive-project.php` is using a custom query to display the posts. And you have declared it as Page template by adding `Template Name` in a comment block, so you are able to assign it to `applications` page. As the result `www.website.com/applications` loads this template file.

`www.website.com/project` also uses the same template file because of its file name  `archive-project.php`.  This is how Wordpress works.

Wordpress uses its **[Template File Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)** to display posts and pages on front-end.

For Custom Post Types with `'has_archive' => true` wordpress use the following order of [template files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates) to render the archive:

1. `archive-{post_type}.php` – If the post type is `project`, WordPress will look for `archive-project.php`
2. `archive.php`
3. `index.php`

The post displayed by above files are selected and fetched from db using main query, so no custom query is required here.

However, some developers choose to create a **[Custom Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)** for displaying the archive of posts. This file can have any valid file name e.g. `my-awsome-template.php`. However, care should be taken to avoid file names that collide with standard wordpress template file names. e.g. `archive.php` or `archive-project.php` etc.

These template files are created by adding `Template Name` in a comment block, something like this.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

It’s a good idea to choose a name that describes what the template does as the name is visible to WordPress users when they are editing the page. For example, you could name your template `Homepage`, `Blog`, or `Portfolio`.

Now this template can be assigned to any pages on the **Page > Edit** screen.
One of the characteristic of custom templates is the use of custom queries to fetch and display posts from db usin `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` and generally does not use Wordpress main query.

**The Solution**

> How to remove the www.website.com/project

You are using custom page template to display the archive and do not want to use mechanism used by wordpress to display archive of posts. So set `'has_archive' => false` where you register your post type `project`. It is also recommended to rename the `archive-project.php` to something else.

Comment: "However, some developers choose to create a Custom Page Template for displaying the archive of posts." Which is incorrect, and the reason a question is posted every other day asking why pagination is broken. Archives should use the template hierarchy and default query.

Comment: @quisar I tried 'has_archive' => false. but now www.website.com/project is loading the template index.php

Comment: @Vivek you need to flush your rewrite rules. In admin area visit  Settings -> Permalinks and click "Save Changes" to  flush your rewrite rules.